# Declaring a method that its parameter is a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface defined like this:

```
public interface IOwlAnnotationTuple<T1, T2, T3>
```

and then also its class like this:

```
public class OwlAnnotationTuple : IOwlAnnotationTuple<string, OWLClass, string>
```

Then I have anther interface that I am adding a method to it which I want it to take a parameter of this interface I defined above, so I defined it like this but I get error that "> is expected."

```
void AddAnnotation(IOwlAnnotationTuple <string annotationName, OWLClass owlClass, string annotationValue>);
```

So what is the correct syntax of declaring it?

Comment: That parameter declaration doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to indicate?

Comment: I want to keep a list of some objects, each object has a "Name, Value, and Relation" like "John-lives in- Japan", so that interface and class to define them...that method to add objects of them to some list in memory...

Comment: I still don't understand what you're after. Should your `AddAnnotation` have a single parameter of type `OwlAnnotationTuple` (or the interface it implements), or three parameters of types `string`, `OWLClass` and `string`?

Comment: @hvd : a single parameter of type OwlAnnotationTuple

Comment: @SLaks : What do you see wrong with those definitions? please let me know so if my whole design thought is wrong I can fix it sooner than later. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've attempted to name three parameters, but if you only want a single one, only name the single one:

```
void AddAnnotation(IOwlAnnotationTuple<string, OWLClass, string> owlAnnotationTuple);
```

or

```
void AddAnnotation(OwlAnnotationTuple owlAnnotationTuple);
```

The type of `owlAnnotationTuple` is `IOwlAnnotationTuple<string, OWLClass, string>`. There are no separate parameters of types `string`/`OWLClass`, so you don't get to name those.